# Изменение расположения изображений @media

Tags: html, css

При нормальном размере экрана выглядеть должно вот так

```
<img id="pic_1" style="padding-right: 50px;" 
src="ссылка" />
<img id="pic_2" style="padding-left: 50px;" 
src="ссылка" />
```

Когда сжимаю экран выглядеть должно вот так (по итогу при сжатии, картинки должны отцентровываться):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) { 
#pic_1{ 
display: table-cell; 
text-align: center;
} 
#pic_2{ 
display: table-cell; 
text-align: center; 
} 
}
```

Не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного не то центруешь. Центровать надо данные внутри блока. Накладывая `text-align: center` на картинку ты пытаешься, данные внутри картинки(?) выровнять по центру.

```
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) { 
  .main {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

**Живой пример:**

http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/QNgbOz